# Photoshop create absolute Selection from "Select Color Range"

Tags: photoshop

I've selected a color range with Photoshops "Color Range" tool, but the selection is a bit transparent. I want to delete the selected color.

Is there a way to make everything completly selected or not at all?
[image: Before]

Now there are a few transparent things:
[image: After]

Comment: Not a Photoshop user (I use Gimp, but obviously they work the same). What you want is not "select black pixels and delete". What you want is "delete the black in pixels and replace it by transparency". In Gimp this is called "Color to Alpha". Better ask on [GDSE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the black pixels are not EXACTLY the "same black". One is per example 99% of black and an other one 100%. So it's two different colors. These colors seems to be the same but they are differents.
So you must add or remove colors like said here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/selecting-color-range-image.html

Holding "Shift" key and mouse click you can add colors of selection and with "Alt" key you can remove (but i'm not sure, using Gimp).